# How to conditionally expect particular characters if a prior regex matched?

Tags: regex, conditional-statements

I want to expect some characters only if a prior regex matched. If not, no characters (empty string) is expected.
For instance, if after the first four characters appears a string out of the group (A10, B32, C56, D65) (kind of enumeration) then a "_" followed by a 3-digit number like 123 is expected. If no element of the mentioned group appears, no other string is expected.
My first attempt was this but the ELSE branch does not work:

```
^XXX_(?<DT>A12|B43|D14)(?(DT)(_\d{1,3})|)\.ZZZ$
```

- XXX_A12_123.ZZZ --> match
- XXX_A11.ZZZ --> match
- XXX_A12_abc.ZZZ --> no match
- XXX_A23_123.ZZZ --> no match

These are examples of filenames. If the filename contains a string of the mentioned group like A12 or C56, then I expect that this element if followed by an underscore followed by 1 to 3 digits. If the filename does not contain a string of that group (no character or a character sequence different from the strings in the group) then I don't want to see the underscore followed by 1 to 3 digits.

For instance, I could extend the regex to

```
^XXX_(?<DT>A12|B43|D14)_\d{5}(?(DT)(_\d{1,3})|)_someMoreChars\.ZZZ$
```

...and then I want these filenames to be valid:

- XXX_A12_12345_123_wellDone.ZZZ
- XXX_Q21_00000_wellDone.ZZZ
- XXX_Q21_00000_456_wellDone.ZZZ

...but this is invalid:

- XXX_A12_12345_wellDone.ZZZ

How can I make the ELSE branch of the conditional statement work?

In the end I intend to have two groups like
Group A: (A11, B32, D76, R33)
Group B: (A23, C56, H78, T99)

If an element of group A occurs in the filename then I expect to find _\d{1,3} in the filename.
If an element of group B occurs ion the filename then the _\d{1,3} shall be optional (it may or may not occur in the filename).

I ended up in this regex:

<strike>^XXX_(?:(?A12|B43|D14))?(?(DT)(_\d{5}_\d{1,3})|(?!(?&DT))(?!.*_\d{3}(?!\d))).*\.ZZZ$</strike>

```
^XXX_(?:(?<DT>A12|B43|D14))?_\d{5}(?(DT)(_\d{1,3})|(?!(?&DT))(?!.*_\d{3}(?!\d))).+\.ZZZ$
```

Since I have to use this regex in the OpenApi @Pattern annotation I have the problem that I get the error:

> Conditionals are not supported in this regex dialect.

As @The fourth bird suggested alternation seems to do the trick:

```
XXX_((((A12|B43|D14)_\d{5}_\d{1,3}))|((?:(A10|B10|C20)((?:_\d{5}_\d{3})|(?:_\d{3}))))).*\.ZZZ$
```

Comment: Sounds like  ["lookahead" `(?=`...`)`](https://javascript.info/regexp-lookahead-lookbehind#lookahead) and ["lookbehind" `(?>`...`)`](https://javascript.info/regexp-lookahead-lookbehind#lookbehind)

Comment: `a prior regex matched` There is no break in the regex. Regex match from left to right. If it matches it does, if not it doesn't. No such thing as a prior match really (that you would know about as a beginner).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The else branch is the part after the `|`, but if you also want to match the 2nd example, the if clause would not work as you have already matched one of `A12|B43|D14`

The named capture group is not optional, so the if clause will always be true.

What you can do instead is use an alternation to match either  the numeration part followed by an underscore and 3 digits, or match an uppercase char and 2 digits.

```
^XXX_(?:(?<DT>A12|B43|D14)_\d{1,3}|[A-Z]\d{2})\.ZZZ$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tsbZFR/1)

If you want to make use of the if/else clause, you can make the named capture group optional, and then check if group 1 exists.

```
^XXX_(?<DT>A12|B43|D14)?(?(DT)_\d{1,3}|[A-Z]\d{2})\.ZZZ$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dg4Uii/1)

For the updated question:

```
^XXX_(?<DT>A12|B43|D14)?(?(DT)(?:_\d{5})?_\d{3}(?!\d)|(?!A12|B43|D14|[A-Z]\d{2}_\d{3}(?!\d))).*\.ZZZ$
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `XXX_` Match literally
- `(?<DT>A12|B43|D14)?`
- `(?(DT)` If we have group DT

  - `(?:_\d{5})?` Optionally match _ and 5 digits
  - `_\d{3}(?!\d)` Match `_` and 3 digits
  - `|` Or
  - `(?!` Negative lookahead, assert not to the right

    - `A12|B43|D14|` Match one of the alternatives, or
    - `[A-Z]\d{2}_\d{3}(?!\d)` Match 1 char A-Z, 2 digits _ 3 digits not followed by a digit
  - `)` Close lookahead
- `)` Close if clause
- `.*` Match the rest of the line
- `\.ZZZ` Match `.` and ZZZ
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/d4SIZ3/1)

Comment: The named group is mandatory in the filename.

Comment: @du-it You can also use the named group for the first pattern with the alternation. I have updated it.

Comment: Your update allows a filename like XXX_A12.ZZZ which is NOT a valid filename because when an element of the group appears in the filename (A12) then it's mandatory that it is followed by _\d{1,3}

Comment: @du-it Why is this one valid? `XXX_Q21_00000_wellDone.ZZZ`

Comment: Because Q21 is not a member of the group. In such a case I don't require the "_\{1,3}

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: @du-it Perhaps like https://regex101.com/r/z58WwY/1

Comment: Cool! Quite close. XXX_Q21_00000_456_wellDone.ZZZ is a valid filename as well.  (My fault in the question. Sorry.) The 456 may occur but it is not mandatory. Did you noticed my update?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240220/discussion-between-du-it-and-the-fourth-bird).

Comment: @du-it This might work for you https://regex101.com/r/fcHQ7c/1 `^XXX_(?<DT>A12|B43|D14)?(?(DT)(?:_\d{5})?_\d{1,3}(?!\d)|(?!A12|B43|D14|[A-Z]\d{2}_\d{3}(?!\d))).*\.ZZZ$`

Comment: @du-it Did it work out?

Comment: I updated my question and I found a solution based upon your answer. (What do you think about ist?) It works well on www.regex101.com but I have to use it in the OpenApi @Annotation and I get an error: 'Conditionals are not supported in this regex dialect.'

Comment: Of course: ...OpenApi @Pattern annotation

Comment: @du-it The pattern that you added to the updated question also does not match all the examples https://regex101.com/r/8y13rt/1

Comment: @du-it You might rewrite it using an alternation `^XXX_(?:(?<DT>A12|B43|D14)(_\d{5}_\d{1,3})|(?!A12|B43|D14)(?!.*_\d{3}(?!\d))).*\.ZZZ$` https://regex101.com/r/Cozs92/1

Comment: You're right, thank you. I modified it and updated my question. Now I check your comment concerning alternation...trying to understand.

Comment: @du-it You have updated the question 9 times now and keep adding,/changing examples. Are you sure that it is complete now?

Comment: The ugly alternation seems to be the (a) solution for the unsupported conditionals. Great job! (Would accept your help/answer twice if possible. ;-) )